# React native and redux persist not working

Tags: react-native, jsx, redux-persist

I am using redux-persist to store the data in my react-native app.
This is the code:

store.js

```jsx
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {
  persistStore,
 persistCombineReducers,
} from 'redux-persist';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import user from './reducers/user';
import auth from './reducers/auth';

const config = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
};

const reducers = persistCombineReducers(config, {
  user,
  auth
});

export const configureStore = () => {
 const store = createStore(
  reducers,
   compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    )
  );
  const persistor = persistStore(store);

  return { persistor, store };
};
```

Then in the App.js I have this :

```jsx
const { persistor, store } = configureStore();
 const onBeforeLift = () => {
  // take some action before the gate lifts
  store.dispatch(startingApp());
}
return (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate
      loading={<HomeLoader />}
      onBeforeLift={onBeforeLift}
      persistor={persistor}>
        <RootNav />
      </PersistGate>
  </Provider>
```

Everything works fine when I dispatch and action from the App.js componentDidMount. 
The problem is that when I fire the action from  component, for example, the state is not stored, so when I restart the app the state is gone.

What I do in  is just calling the action and passing the data:

```jsx
this.props.onSetAuthData(data.credentials);
```

The state is updated as I can see in the console, but if I restart the app, only the state created by the action in App.js is saved, not the one in

Maybe this has to do with the RootNav component ?

maybe I am exporting wrong the reducers? 
I have 
    const user = (state = initialState, action = {}) => {}
    export default user.
Same for the other reducer:
    const auth = (state = initialState, action = {}) => {}
    export default auth.

Then I export with
    combineReducers({auth, user})

Is this wrong?

Comment: actually I found it out that is not persisting at all, because I removed the store.dispatch(startingApp()); and now nothing is persisted, can't understand what I am doing wrong. Any help?

Comment: It looks like I am exporting wrong the reducers.

Comment: which is the redux-persist version you are using ?

Answer (score 2):

Use tool like Reacttotron to see if your store is persisted or not.

https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron

If it's already persisted your component should wait until the store rehydrated on app launch. Sometimes I can't use the redux persist using `persistgate` to wait for the persisted store to be rehydrated. So I set the store and persistor into state on `async componentWillMount` then in your render, check if the store is not empty (null) and already rehydrated then load your app.

```jsx
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {store: null, persistor: null}
  }
  async componentWillMount () {
    const store = configureStore();
    this.setState({ store: store.store })
    this.setState({ persistor: store.persistor })
  }
  render(){
    return (
    if (this.state.store === null) {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>Loading...</Text>
        </View>
        );
    }
    <Provider store={this.state.store} persistor={this.state.persistor}>
          <RootNav />
    </Provider>
```

Also try to change your storage from `AsyncStorage` to `storage`.

```jsx
const config = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
};
```

First import the storage `import storage from 'redux-persist/es/storage';`

Comment: I have created and tried to persist the store like this only.But after clearing the app from recent apps,store gets initial state means my state is not persisting in storage.Please tell me what will be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes it calls an error with the key in **persistConfig**. try key: '**primary**'

```
const primary = {
key: 'root',
storage: AsyncStorage,
blacklist: [],
whitelist: ['user'],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was actually a problem with the AsyncStorage library itself(also see this [issue](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/809)).

I ended up writing my own Nativemodule with getItem, setItem, and removeItem etc methods, after which it worked seamlessly.

I added more details on my friend's blog [here](http://www.asheeshpathak.in/redux-persist-not-working/)

Hope it helps someone.